# Aligning images within parent element horizontally

Tags: html, css

I feel like a complete noob with this question, but I cannot get anything to work. I have social media icons within my footer and I want to center them within the block they are in.

I have tried `text-align: center` and `margin: 0 auto;`. Neither has worked.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use following css will make you social icon to center withing block.

```
#footer-social-images {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3cLz50x/)**

Comment: How could I do it with a series if inline block images? Say there are 6 boxes, 2 rows of them and 3 columns.

Comment: @Becky Here `.wrap {
    text-align: center;
}` can do the trick. https://jsfiddle.net/3m9c1woh/1/

Comment: Thanks again for your help!